# How to make sure that child html element does not get out of bootstrap columns

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, grid

I am attaching a link to my parent element below which is basically a `<div class="col-md-8">`:-

[image]

Below I am attaching an image of a child element which is flowing out of the parent element:-

[image]

How do I start inspecting this issue to figure out why the child element is flowing out of the parent element. I am trying to make sure that the stays inside the parent element.

Comment: Can you share the error you are getting

Comment: Please check out the images I have add, in first image I have bootstrap columns which is a parent div and in the second image there is a child element which is getting outside of the parent element. I am trying to make sure that the child element does not get outside of the parent element. @Basta

Answer (score 2, accepted):

basically. It flows out because it the table doesn't fit inside `col-md-8`.

it has too many columns.

to avoid overflow, you can add: `overflow-auto` to `col-md-8` to make it scroll horizontally.

example without `overflow-auto`

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4">
      some content
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-8" style="background-color: blue">
      <table>
        <tbody>
          <tr>
            <td>column 1</td>
            <td>column 2</td>
            <td>column 3</td>
            <td>column 4</td>
            <td>column 5</td>
            <td>column 6</td>
            <td>column 7</td>
            <td>column 8</td>
            <td>column 9</td>
            <td>column 10</td>
            <td>column 11</td>
            <td>column 12</td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

example with `overflow-auto`

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4">
      some content
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-8 overflow-auto" style="background-color: blue">
      <table>
        <tbody>
          <tr>
            <td>column 1</td>
            <td>column 2</td>
            <td>column 3</td>
            <td>column 4</td>
            <td>column 5</td>
            <td>column 6</td>
            <td>column 7</td>
            <td>column 8</td>
            <td>column 9</td>
            <td>column 10</td>
            <td>column 11</td>
            <td>column 12</td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot but having a scroll at the bottom is not an option for me.

Comment: so the only way is to reduce the content of your sidebar

Comment: also you can customize scrollbr style